# QProcess doesn't start python script

Tags: python, qt, qprocess

I am using QT and trying to call a python script

```
QProcess *my_process= new QProcess;
QString path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/PASTE/";
QStringList arguments = QStringList() << path+"script.py"  << arg1 << arg2<< arg3;
my_process->start("python", arguments);
my_process->waitForFinished();
```

The problem is that the python script doesn't run, and if i instead use startDetached() it actually runs, but i need to use start() to because later in the code i need to use a finished signal, and startDetached() can't emit this signal.

So i want to run the script with start(), but it isn't working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: show the content of script.py

Comment: Try: connecting to finished(), errorOccurred(), check return value, error code, errorString() and read the process stdout and stderror